# Posting varying amount of images from a form

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm attempting to build a form with a few textbox inputs and a file input for someone to upload images.

When a file is picked, I have some JS go get a partial view and render it in the form.  After the new partial is rendered, I clone and copy the file input element and place it as a hidden input in the new partial to be used later in the form.  There's some other fields in the partial that relate to the image that was selected.

Once that's all done, the file input element is reset, and the user can select another image, generating a new partial view, etc.

The form looks like it's being rendered correctly, but when I try to submit, VS memory/cpu usage spikes, and the request never makes it to the controller.  Any advice or help here is appreciated!

[Screenshot of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZbKo.png)

ViewModel:

```
  public class ProjectCreate
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProjectDate { get; set; }
    public List<Image> GalleryImages { get; set; }
  }
```

Image ViewModel:

```
  public class Image
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int GalleryIndex { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IFormFile ImageFile { get; set; }
  }
```

Form:

```
    <form asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
        <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
        <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
        <label asp-for="ProjectDate" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="ProjectDate" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="ProjectDate" class="text-danger"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
        <label class="control-label">Project Images</label>
        <input id="ImageUpload" type="file" class="form-control" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif" />
      </div>

      @* Display images here *@
      <div id="pending-images" class="row"></div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
      </div>
    </form>
```

The 'pending-images' div is where the partialview is rendered to.

PartialView:

```
<div class="card mb-3" style="width: 18rem">
  <img class="card-img-top" id="pending-image-@Model.Id" src="" style="max-height: 18rem; max-width: 18rem;" />
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Index</label>
      <input id="GalleryImages[@Model.Id].GalleryIndex" name="GalleryImages[@Model.Id].GalleryIndex" class="form-control" value="@Model.Id" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Name/Title</label>
      <input id="GalleryImages[@Model.Id].Name" name="GalleryImages[@Model.Id].Name" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Description</label>
      <input id="GalleryImages[@Model.Id].Description" name="GalleryImages[@Model.Id].Description" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <input type="file" id="GalleryImages[@Model.Id].ImageFile" name="GalleryImages[@Model.Id].ImageFile" style="display: none;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/Projects/Create" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">

  <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <label class="control-label" for="Title">Title</label>
    <input class="form-control valid" type="text" id="Title" name="Title" value="" aria-invalid="false">
    <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Title" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <label class="control-label" for="Description">Description</label>
    <input class="form-control valid" type="text" id="Description" name="Description" value="" aria-invalid="false">
    <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Description"
          data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <label class="control-label" for="ProjectDate">Project Date</label>
    <input class="form-control valid" type="date" data-val="true"
           data-val-required="The Project Date field is required." id="ProjectDate" name="ProjectDate" value=""
           aria-describedby="ProjectDate-error" aria-invalid="false">
    <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ProjectDate"
          data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <label class="control-label">Project Images</label>
    <input id="ImageUpload" type="file" class="form-control" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif">
  </div>

  <div id="pending-images" class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="card mb-3" style="width: 18rem">
        <img class="card-img-top" id="pending-image-0" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,xxx"
             style="max-height: 18rem; max-width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Index</label>
            <input id="GalleryImages[0].GalleryIndex" name="GalleryImages[0].GalleryIndex"
                   class="form-control" value="0">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Name/Title</label>
            <input id="GalleryImages[0].Name" name="GalleryImages[0].Name" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Description</label>
            <input id="GalleryImages[0].Description" name="GalleryImages[0].Description"
                   class="form-control">
          </div>
          <input id="GalleryImages[0].ImageFile" type="file" class="form-control"
                 accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif" name="GalleryImages[0].ImageFile"
                 style="display:none;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary">
  </div>
  <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="xxx">
</form>
```

When there's more than one image trying to be uploaded, only the first image shows up the in the Fiddler info.  I can also upload that or anything else if it would be helpful.  I tried to include everything though.  Is there a better way to accomplish this?  I'm thinking about trying to hook into imgur or something similar if I can't work this out.

Comment: The input tag of `type="file"` should reference `multiple' if you want to upload multiple files at once. You'll also need a foreach loop to cycle through viewdata.

Comment: @SRQCoder even when there are multiple file input's on the page? Unfortunately requests are not even making it to the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use your input like this :

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="files" id="files" />
```

I don't know if you can use the type="image" here, but you can certainly use your controler to check if the user only uploaded images.

Or you may be able to add this parameter to the input.

```
accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
```

Comment: Thanks Tortillas, I'll give that a shot when I get home.  I figured if I had multiple input type="file" the model binder would pick them up. I even tried to name and id them just like how .NET would like 'GalleryImages[0].ImageFile' and 'GalleryImages[1].ImageFile'

Comment: I understand, also on your post controller, if you are using the input type="file", you will be able to acces the files with a parameter like this : IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files